# Android Studio: Virtual device (Nexus 4/5) is showing black screen for all versions of Android

Tags: android, performance

I need to use Android Studio for my education, but I've been struggling getting it to work.

My hardware specs are: Intel SL9400 1.86 GHz Duo, 4 GB DDR3-1066 MHz, Integrated graphics, 1280x800 resoulution screen and 250 GB Samsung Evo SSD.

I've been searching Google for an explanation, but nothing of the suggestions seems to help. Some mentions OpenGL support?

The black screen is happening both with GPU-enabled as well as disabled, and I've tried Android versions below (including) version 15 and above up to 23.

Android Studio is updated to the newest version, and I've installed the latest SDK.

Below I've attached a snippet of the endless terminal output, as well as a screenshot the scenario.

I really hope that someone can help me out - I need this to work before Tuesday :(.

[image]

```
08-30 07:13:34.037    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 17% free 1712K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:34.107    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 16% free 1733K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:34.157    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 64K, 13% free 1785K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:34.268    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 13% free 1801K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:34.547    1495-1495/? I/System﹕ Loaded time zone names for  in 244ms (242ms in ICU)
08-30 07:13:34.757    1495-1495/? I/System﹕ Loaded time zone names for en_US in 202ms (200ms in ICU)
08-30 07:13:34.797    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 304K, 15% free 1915K/2243K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:34.827    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 13% free 1973K/2243K, paused 10ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:34.897    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 49K, 11% free 2004K/2243K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:34.997    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 10% free 2034K/2243K, paused 0ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:35.077    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 9% free 2052K/2243K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:35.177    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 8% free 2074K/2243K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:35.207    1495-1495/? I/Zygote﹕ ...preloaded 2297 classes in 4030ms.
08-30 07:13:35.227    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 8% free 2077K/2243K, paused 1ms+2ms
08-30 07:13:35.227    1495-1495/? I/Zygote﹕ Preloading resources...
08-30 07:13:35.247    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d7 (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_black_16.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.267    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d8 (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_black_20.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.306    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d9 (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_black_48.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.327    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 50K, 10% free 2194K/2435K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:35.377    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804da (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_black_76.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.456    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 83K, 14% free 2376K/2755K, paused 3ms+2ms
08-30 07:13:35.497    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e8 (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_white_16.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.517    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e9 (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_white_48.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.557    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 43K, 11% free 2467K/2755K, paused 0ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:35.636    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804ea (res/drawable-xhdpi/spinner_white_76.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.757    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 83K, 11% free 2649K/2947K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:35.787    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080096 (res/drawable-xhdpi/toast_frame.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.837    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 61K, 12% free 2784K/3139K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:35.877    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805d0 (res/drawable-xhdpi/toast_frame_holo.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:35.907    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 61K, 13% free 2920K/3331K, paused 2ms+2ms
08-30 07:13:35.948    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080106 (res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_check_on_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:36.008    1499-1499/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger is starting
08-30 07:13:36.008    1499-1500/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
08-30 07:13:36.077    1499-1500/? D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 07:13:36.087    1495-1495/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 30K, 11% free 2984K/3331K, paused 3ms+2ms
08-30 07:13:36.108    1499-1500/? E/FramebufferNativeWindow﹕ couldn't open framebuffer HAL (No such file or directory)
08-30 07:13:36.108    1499-1500/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Display subsystem failed to initialize. check logs. exiting...
08-30 07:13:36.127    1495-1495/? W/Zygote﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080105 (res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
08-30 07:13:36.288    1502-1502/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
08-30 07:13:36.318    1502-1502/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
08-30 07:13:37.027    1502-1502/? I/SamplingProfilerIntegration﹕ Profiling disabled.
08-30 07:13:37.077    1502-1502/? I/Zygote﹕ Preloading classes...
08-30 07:13:37.086    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 81% free 400K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:37.117    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 78% free 463K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:37.347    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 76% free 498K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:37.447    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 75% free 526K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:37.506    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 73% free 567K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:37.617    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 71% free 594K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:37.726    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 70% free 623K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:37.747    1502-1502/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
08-30 07:13:37.776    1502-1502/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
08-30 07:13:37.836    1502-1502/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-30 07:13:37.836    1502-1502/? D/MtpDeviceJNI﹕ register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
08-30 07:13:37.847    1502-1502/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-30 07:13:37.847    1502-1502/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-30 07:13:37.857    1502-1502/? W/MediaProfiles﹕ could not find media config xml file
08-30 07:13:37.867    1502-1502/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
08-30 07:13:37.867    1502-1502/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
08-30 07:13:37.887    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 68% free 662K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:38.006    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 215K, 54% free 959K/2048K, paused 6ms
08-30 07:13:38.058    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 51% free 1006K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:38.230    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 50% free 1037K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:38.367    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 47% free 1088K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:38.406    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 44% free 1147K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:38.466    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 46K, 31% free 1418K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:38.487    1502-1502/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount
08-30 07:13:38.546    1502-1502/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1
08-30 07:13:38.666    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 34K, 30% free 1452K/2048K, paused 2ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:38.786    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 28% free 1475K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:38.926    1502-1502/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
08-30 07:13:38.926    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init
08-30 07:13:38.976    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 26% free 1523K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:39.056    1502-1502/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow
08-30 07:13:39.146    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 25% free 1552K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:39.326    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 70K, 22% free 1597K/2048K, paused 2ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:39.376    1502-1502/? E/PhonePolicy﹕ Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
08-30 07:13:39.446    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 21% free 1618K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:39.556    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 20% free 1647K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:39.616    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 19% free 1677K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:39.666    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 17% free 1712K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:39.756    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 16% free 1733K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:39.806    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 64K, 13% free 1785K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:39.886    1502-1502/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 13% free 1801K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:40.196    1502-1502/? I/System﹕ Loaded time zone names for  in 275ms (273ms in ICU)
08-30 07:13:40.456    1506-1506/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger is starting
08-30 07:13:40.456    1506-1507/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
08-30 07:13:40.496    1506-1507/? D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 07:13:40.496    1506-1507/? E/FramebufferNativeWindow﹕ couldn't open framebuffer HAL (No such file or directory)
08-30 07:13:40.496    1506-1507/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Display subsystem failed to initialize. check logs. exiting...
08-30 07:13:40.616    1509-1509/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
08-30 07:13:40.616    1509-1509/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
08-30 07:13:41.106    1509-1509/? I/SamplingProfilerIntegration﹕ Profiling disabled.
08-30 07:13:41.156    1509-1509/? I/Zygote﹕ Preloading classes...
08-30 07:13:41.166    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 81% free 400K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:41.196    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 78% free 463K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:41.336    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 76% free 498K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:41.456    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 75% free 526K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:41.516    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 73% free 567K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:41.676    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 71% free 594K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:41.806    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 70% free 623K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:41.836    1509-1509/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
08-30 07:13:41.856    1509-1509/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
08-30 07:13:41.926    1509-1509/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-30 07:13:41.936    1509-1509/? D/MtpDeviceJNI﹕ register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
08-30 07:13:41.948    1509-1509/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-30 07:13:41.948    1509-1509/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
08-30 07:13:41.956    1509-1509/? W/MediaProfiles﹕ could not find media config xml file
08-30 07:13:41.966    1509-1509/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
08-30 07:13:41.966    1509-1509/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
08-30 07:13:41.986    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 68% free 662K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:42.116    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 216K, 54% free 957K/2048K, paused 6ms
08-30 07:13:42.176    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 36K, 51% free 1006K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:42.286    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 28K, 50% free 1037K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:42.376    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 47% free 1088K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:42.406    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 44% free 1147K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:42.486    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 46K, 31% free 1418K/2048K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:42.516    1509-1509/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount
08-30 07:13:42.576    1509-1509/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1
08-30 07:13:42.626    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 34K, 30% free 1452K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:42.766    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 28% free 1475K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:42.976    1509-1509/? I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
08-30 07:13:42.976    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init
08-30 07:13:43.056    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 26% free 1523K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:43.167    1509-1509/? W/Zygote﹕ Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow
08-30 07:13:43.326    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 25% free 1551K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
08-30 07:13:43.727    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 70K, 23% free 1597K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-30 07:13:43.847    1509-1509/? E/PhonePolicy﹕ Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
08-30 07:13:43.946    1509-1509/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 21% free 1618K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
```

Comment: Use https://www.genymotion.com/ for debugging your app. Never use build in google emulator. It's a crap.

Comment: Is the amount of RAM in your computer free which you are providing to avd

Comment: Yes I give it less than 512 MB.

Comment: In case of Nexus 4/5  1.8-2 GB RAM is recommended...I think you should try that...

Comment: None the less, shouldn't it start ? Can you see anything from the log ?

Comment: @Shuzheng, Did you fixed it?

Comment: @VolodymyrFedorchuk - I recall that my PC wasn't sufficiently powerful to run the emulator - it requires modern hardware. In my case, I bought a cheap Android phone and tested the app using USB connection. Tested the same thing on my desktop PC, there everything works fine.

Comment: @Shuzheng, thank you, for your answer -- I think, I will bought cheap android too.

Comment: @VolodymyrFedorchuk - I would if I should do serious app development. The emulator even runs "slow" on a laptop with Haswell 4720QM + Nvidia 960M. A dedicated smart phone allows for much faster testing. However, you cannot test different models then. On a 7-year old laptop, the emulator starts extremely slow (or can't run).